# Organising home controller of MVC app with lots of static information views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My MVC app will have a lot of views (approx 20 to 30). Currently they are all in my HomeController but it has gotten very long:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";
        return View();
    }

    /* *SNIP* 29 actions later... */
}
```

What is the best way to deal with static content pages in MVC 4? Is it best to put them in the HomeController, or have a separate controller related to each information area?

I really want to avoid using a CMS as MVC is great for all my other requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not passing in any data into the view with a model or viewbag then why not just have one index action and use the path param from the route to determine which view to use?

So something like this

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string path)
    {
        return View(path);
    }    
}
```

**Route**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default", // Route name
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{*path}" // URL with parameters
);
```

Or if you didn't want to have the url contain home/index over and over, then just do this

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name:"Catchall",
    url: "{path}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", path = "DefaultView" }
);
```

Comment: Thanks Jarek that is interesting. Im currently using this code to format to lower case http://mvccoderouting.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Route%20Formatting&referringTitle=Documentation how would I merge that with your suggestion of indexed views?

Comment: Off hand I'm not sure. Seems like the sample you're following only deals with formatting and not defining of a route. Try it out by just adding one of the snippets I posted to the RegisterRoutes method in global.asax and see if it does what you want and works in conjunction with the formatting code.